# How to check whether a Timer Job has run

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wss-3.0, timer-jobs

Is it possible to check whether a SharePoint (actually WSS 3.0) timer job has run when it was scheduled to ?

Reason is we have a few daily custom jobs and want to make sure they're always run, even if the server has been down during the time slot for the jobs to run, so I'd like to check them and then run them

And is it possible to add a setting when creating them similar to the one for standard Windows scheduled tasks ... *"Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed"* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check it in job status page and then you can look at the logs in 12 hive folder for further details

central administration/operations/monitoring/timer jobs/check jobs status

As far as the job restart is concerned when it is missed that would not be possible with OOTB features. and it make sense as well since there are lot of jobs which are executed at particular interval if everything starts at the same time load on server would be very high

Comment: I'm on Central Administration / Operations, but there isn't any Monitoring option ??    ... this is WSS 3.0 ... but there is a Central Administration / Operations / Timer Job Status which has a Started field, which helps, so thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the `LastRunTime` property of an `SPJobDefinition` to see when the job was actually executed. As far as I can see in Reflector, the value of this property is loaded from the database and hence it should reflect the time it was actually executed.